# Airflow worker helm container with another container

Tags: airflow, kubernetes-helm

I have an airflow worker chart with a container that contains the airflow-worker image. Can I add another container in the helm chart that the airflow worker can later execute being in the same Pod?

```
      containers:
        - name: my-airflow-worker
          imagePullPolicy: Ifnotpresent
          image: quay.io/my/my-airflow-worker:demo
        - name: my-python-app-image
          imagePullPolicy: Ifnotpresent
          image: quay.io/my/my-python-app-image:demo
```

Can my airflow workers execute my-python-app-image in the same pod? I have not seen an approach like this but just wondering if there are issues with this implementation. Reason I ask is because I was reading about KubernetesPodOperator and looks like I might be able to achieve the same thing(which is it isolate env and prevent airflow from having to install app dependencies) if I can just add another container with app docker image side-by-side with airflow-worker. I saw examples having a side-car container to sync DAG files to persistent mounted volumes. I think it will be similar to that but different purpose.

Comment: any reason for down vote and how i can improve and provide clarity on the question?

Comment: I also don't see a downvote ... Ehm in regard to the question: Your airflow-worker will not execute the sidecar but as defined it would run continously side by side. So you could call apis in there.

Comment: I think it can if I execute with a `kubectl` command and specify the pod and container.  I triggered a DAG that executes the `kubectl` command and the error I am getting is ` kubectl: command not found`. That means it's possible. But I am not just sure whether this is a good practice and what issues I might be facing later.